# How to configure Django generic view for both GET and POST using model form

Tags: python, django

I want to create a view function + template that displays a simple form (derived from a user model) and also captures the form submission. How do I do this using generic views in Django?

My user model is:

```
class User(models.Model):
   email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I only need to capture the email field in the form.

I think there must be a simple way to do this using generic forms, however I'm not sure which one to use nor how to do it. The only other ways I know how to do it are:

1) Create UserForm explicitly and a single view function separating POST and GET requests. E.g., :

```
def contact(request):
   if request.method == 'GET':
       # display UserForm
        ....
   elif request.method == 'POST':
       # process form submission
        ....
```

2) Create two views (with seperate URLs) - one using generic view to display form and another view to receive form submission e.g.,:

```
class contact(generic.DetailView):
   # display form from User model
   model = User
   ....

def submit(request):
   # process form submission
    ....
```

So, my two questions are:

- can and how should this be implemented using ONLY a generic view?
- which generic view should be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First part of the answer: use a single view. If you use a function view (which is by far the simplest solution), the canonical form-handling edit view looks like:

```
def myview(request, instance_id, ...):
    instance = get_object_or_404(pk=instance_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MyForm(request.POST, ..., instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            # assuming a ModelForm 
            form.save()
            return redirect(somewhere)
        # invalid forms will be re-rendered with the error messages
    else:
        form = MyForm(instance=instance)
    return render(request, "myapp/mytemplate.html", {"form": form})
```

For a create view, you just remove all the instance_xxx parts. Or you can use the same view for both create and update making the `instance_id` optional:

```
def myview(request, instance_id=None, ...):
    if instance_id is not None:
        instance = get_object_or_404(pk=instance_id)
    else:
        instance = None

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MyForm(request.POST, ..., instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            # assuming a ModelForm 
            form.save()
            return redirect(somewhere)
        # invalid forms will be re-rendered with the error messages
    else:
        form = MyForm(instance=instance)
    return render(request, "myapp/mytemplate.html", {"form": form})
```

If you want a class-based generic view [they are documented here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/). I personally don't think there's much to gain from generic class-based views (except eventually headaches when you try to grasp the execution flow scattered amongst half a dozen base classes and mixins) but YMMV.

**update**

> if I want to do some processing on the data (including adding in extra fields) before saving an instance to the DB, where would I do this?

Preferably in the form itself unless you need some other data that you don't want to pass to the form. For all forms you can process data at [the validation stage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/validation/). With a ModelForm you can also override the `save()` method itself:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('whatever', 'something')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        """ Save user and create a pro account """
        instance = super(MyModelForm, self).save(commit=False)
        instance.something_else = 42 
        if commit:
            instance.save()
        return instance
```

Comment: Ok, yes I'm beginning to think the generic views are going to be more of a headache than helpful given all the other stuff built in.... Using your approach - if I want to do some processing on the data (including adding in extra fields) before saving an instance to the DB, where would I do this?

Comment: OK understood. At what point would you start putting that processing in the model itself (or elsewhere)? Part of my 'validation' is to reject form submissions from the same IP too many times, but I wonder whether that is a task to be placed in the model or as some sort of post-processing after the form itself is validated...

Comment: (The other processing I have to do is to check whether the user already exists and forward them to a different URL if that's the case... clearly that has to be done before the form is saved, so not sure where in the process I should build that logic)

Comment: > "At what point would you start putting that processing in the model itself" : there's no one-size-fits-all answer here, it depends on what "processing" is involved, which informations this processing requires, where you need to call it etc. I tend to favor "smart" models as far as I'm concerned but that doesn't mean everything should become a method on the model. I'm afraid the only advise I can come with here is "use your judgement".

Comment: > "check whether the user already exists and forward them to a different URL if that's the case" : this part clearly needs to be addressed at the view level itself (since you want to return an `HttpResponseRedirect`. Assuming you're using the form to validate the email and then use this email to find out whether the user already exists, this might go in the `if form.is_valid():` branch,  before saving the form. But you also want to make sure you have a unicity constraint on the `email` form to prevent duplicated emails from being created via another part of the code.

Comment: Thanks Bruno - I already have the email field set to unique=True in the model, so I'm assuming that will propagate to the ModelForm as well?

Comment: Yes it will. Actually (rethinking about it) if you already have this constraint in your model the form just won't validate (modelforms do check unicity constraints too) - but relying on the ValidationError message is brittle at best :-/. The robust solution here would to override the forms `clean()` method (which is called before unique checks), calling the parents implementation and if the email is technically ok  manually check for duplication and raise a specific exception that you will have to catch in the view and then redirect the user.

Comment: Best here is to first read the doc (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#validation-on-a-modelform), and then read the source code (and/or trace it in the debugger) to make sure you understand the whole process.

Comment: Update: you could also set the form's `_validate_unique` attribute to `False` to prevent the form from doing this part, and do the unicity check manually in the view after the call to `form.is_valid()` and before the `form.save()`. `_validate_unique` being set by `BaseModelForm.clean()`, the simple solution is to override `clean()` to only return `self.cleaned_data` __without__ calling the parent's implementation - but you'd better clearly document it so someone coming later doesn't think it's a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

`CreateView` can work perfectly according to your requirements, You only need to create a form of contact models and `success_url` where user will redirect after form submission. It'll save automatic user data into models

```
class ContactView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = ContactForm
    template_name = 'contact/index.html'
    success_url = '/homepage/' . #Mention URL here
```

Comment: If I do that, what happens to the form once submitted?(I need to know so that I can do some operations on the submitted data before saving to the DB)

Comment: When user submitter once form then it'll automatic validate form data and also save user data in model and will redirect to use at `success_url`, If user data is not valid then it'll return the same page to user with entered data. 
flow of CreateView https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done using only `CreateView`.Specify `email` in `fields` as you need only the email field in the form.You can also process submitted form in `form_valid` method.

```
 class UserCreate(CreateView):
    model = User
    fields = ['email']
    success_url = '/your_success_url/'

    @transaction.atomic
    def form_valid(self, form):
       new_user = form.save(commit=False)
       # process your submitted form here.
       # eg. add any extra fields as:
       # new_user.something = something
       new_user.save()
       return super().form_valid(form)
```